# Which are the maths operations behind Local Orientation Transform, when changing Location for randomly rotated Object in 3D Viewport Editor?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, interface, drivers, transform-orientation

This is a theoretical question.
Hi there.

I've just found that it's quite challenging (if at all possible) to reproduce what the Local Orientation Transform actually does to an Object (e.g., a simple Cube Mesh Object) in the 3D Viewport Editor.
The Cube Mesh Object's Location data (from X, Y, Z, at Item Tab ← N-Panel/Sidebar ← 3D Viewport Editor for exemple) are just Local Coordinates -based Values (which may or may not match World Coordinates depending on the Origin 'root' positioning with Apply Location); there is apparently no such thing as an accessible **"Dynamic" Coordinates** for an Object and immediately accessible to the user on the Blender UI (as the Local Coordinates already presented). "Dynamic" Coordinates would be the mathematical output of a 'Rotated Grid system' in relation to the Local Coordinates regular 'Grid system' (which has exactly the same orientation as the World Coordinates 'Grid system'; everytime an Object is Rotated, that imaginary "Dynamic" Grid (with all its 'Dynamic' Coordinates) would be re-actualized (this is for now just an imaginary model, as I don't know if this truly exists somewhat this way inside Blender).

If this is plausible (to reproduce Local Orientation Transform feature for Location Transformation), I can imagine that it would take the creation of at least (probably, more than) 1 Driver for each of those Local Coordinates (X,Y,Z Values) of the Cube Mesh Object to start to be able to emulate what the Local Orientation Transform actually does to Objects in the 3D Viewport Editor. There could be other ways around naturally; but Drivers just immediately popped up to my mind.

Note that changing, for instance, the X Location Value directly on the Value Button (N-Panel), even if Local Orientation Transform is set, because this single selected Value is one of a Local Coordinates 'Grid system' (and not one like making part of a post-calculated "Dynamic" Coordinates 'Grid system'), it moves the Cube only in parallel to the World X-Axis —as it should be expected.

To reproduce the Local Orientation Transform for Location Transformation, it would take simultaneous changes' inputs (often on different rates/speeds of change for each of the Axes components) to at least 2 (sometimes 3) of the X, Y, Z Location Values as Local Coordinates.
This is why I thought about Drivers.

So, Blender is already doing this automatically (when we use the Local Orientation Transform to move (Grab) an Object in the 3D Viewport, but only presents the composed output; there is simply no direct input in the UI for it apparently —as far as I've investigated. Not in Properties Editor (as far as I've seen), not in the Graph Editor (as the available channels there are, also, Local Coordinates -based.

Thus, it makes it even more intriguing to know: how is Blender calculating, "translating" those data actually? It can't be too complicated and I believe I could solve this myself with some research (I mean on paper, not inside Blender) if I revised some good fundamentals in fields of Mathematics. I guess it would probably take Analytic Geometry, Trigonometry and… (maybe not necessarily, but can't be sure), Matrices' operations or sort of transformation function? Really curious anyways.

I thought about checking Scripts inside Blender… but I've got about 0 insight in this domain of the software as of yet. Maybe that would be the way to start spotting ('unhiding') some interesting data and information relative to my question?
In such case, can I ask for some guides or tips that would relate to this particular investigation?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It's a little too long...

Comment: @YousufChaudhry Sorry, but, it's my first topic on Blender StackExchange; and it just happened that the issue is not that trivial. I assumed it would be fairer to my readers if I added enough contextual information on the whole problematic. ¿But maybe that was not such a good idea? I don't really understand that perspective. ¿Are you trying to point me to a generic rule on the site I might have missed and to make retakes on my text to have it shrinked or simplified? or ¿suggesting that the topic questions may be complex but should be resumed in a few lines? Thanks.

Comment: No, there's no such rule. However, most people won't have the time to read such a long explanation. If it's possible to summarize it slightly, do it, but if it can't be shorter, it's okay :)

Comment: Yes; I think I can actually make some improvements to the text on that regard. But it might take some days —more or less slight cleaning up of redundancies should help. ;)